# How to prove that this statistic is not sufficient?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, bernoulli-distribution, sufficient-statistics

**Problem.**

Given $X_1,X_2,X_3$ a random sample from the Bernoulli distribution with success $\theta$, show that the statistic $T= X_1+2X_2+3X_3$ is not sufficient.

**My attempt**

When I try to apply the factorization criterion I don't see this function inside the likelihood so I guess $T$ is not sufficient. However, I feel unsure if this is the right proof... Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Apply the definition of sufficiency, not the factorization criterion and argue by contradiction: assume $T$ is sufficient, cmpute $P_\theta(X_1=1,X_2=1,X_3=0|T=3)$. Do you see the contradiction?

Comment: see also [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/596636/56940) for a similar question, which may be helpful to compute the conditional probabilty.

Comment: thank you very very much!

Comment: Interestingly, slight variants of this statistic, such as $T_{1,2,4}=X_1+2X_2+4X_3,$ *are* sufficient!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the hints provided by @utobi in the comments of my post, I think I got the answer myself. The conditional probability of observing the sample 1,1,0, given the statistic $T=3$ is

$$
P_\theta(X_1=1,X_2=1,X_3=0|T=3) = \frac{P_\theta(X_1=1,X_2=1,X_3=0,T=3)}{P_\theta(T=3)}\\
= \theta.
$$

Since this probability does depend on $\theta$, $T$ is not sufficient.