# Is $ T = X_1 +5 X_2 $ sufficient estimator of $p$?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics

> If $ X_1 $ and $ X_2$  are $\textrm{Ber}(p)$ random variables, examine the sufficiency of $ T_1 = X_1 + 5 X_2 $ for $ p .$

I have no idea on how to proceed, I tried to use the conditional distribution but I got stuck.

Comment: Sufficient for what?

Comment: @dimitriy I have added , thanks for letting me know

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/597068/56940

Comment: @utobi's approach is feasible. You can update your attempts here, if you are still stuck. And while I have added this time [tag:self-study], please don't forget in the future to add the same.

Comment: Also, check [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3131087/showing-hat-theta-fracx-1-2x-2-x-34-is-a-not-a-sufficient-estima?rq=1) that goes along the same line.

Comment: @user1865345  I will look into the post , and update my answer